# My buttons in Pygame are not changing colors due to overlapping

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making my first game in pygame, and so far (thanks to the great answers on here) I am getting a handle on how to go from image to image based on the player's choices. However my buttons are supposed to be highlighting when the cursor moves over them. While the initial buttons do this, I've noticed that if a button on one image is in the same place as a button on one of the previous images then it doesn't highlight. If it's partially overlapping on space where a previous button was, then moving the cursor over that partial part of the button won't highlight the button until you move the cursor to the part of the button which isn't overlapping (hopefully that makes sense, for instance; Wait3Button won't highlight since it overlaps directly where WaitButton was). Is there a way I could use true/false variables to lock which buttons highlight and which don't after certain images? Or any other type of solution? SIDE NOTE; I figured out how to put my button class in another file and import it. Any tips on doing this with functions? I plan on having several functions as I want my game to have several branching choices. Thanks guys. Sorry for the long post, just excited about making this game and want to be as clear as possible. Here is code from my main file:::

```
import pygame
from Game2 import button
pygame .init()
pygame .font .init()  ##  don't need to initialize font every turn, just do it once
screensize = Width, Height = 800, 700
halfwidth, halfheight = Width /2, Height /2
win = pygame .display .set_mode( screensize )
our_game_display = pygame .Surface( screensize )
font_name = pygame .font .get_default_font()
sansfont = pygame .font .SysFont( 'comicsans',  30 )
fontsize = 20
origin = 0, 0  ##  use variables for commonly used values
black = 0, 0, 0
blue = 0,  0,  139
white = 255, 255, 255
def draw_text( text,  size,  x,  y ):
        font = pygame .font .Font( font_name,  size )
        text_surface = font .render( text,  True,  white )
        text_rect = text_surface .get_rect()
        text_rect .center = ( x,  y )
        our_game_display .blit( text_surface,  text_rect )
def keep_waiting_3():
    our_game_display .fill(black)
    draw_text('Nothing still...wait! You hear something!', 20, halfwidth, halfheight - 100)
    win .blit(our_game_display, origin)
    pygame .display .update()
def keep_waiting_2():
    our_game_display.fill(black)
    draw_text('Are you sure you want to keep waiting?', 20, halfwidth, halfheight - 100)
    draw_text("Maybe this isn't worth it...You could always choose the other options.", 20, halfwidth, halfheight - 50)
    win .blit(our_game_display, origin)
    Wait3Button .draw( win, white)
    SearchButton .draw(win, white)
    YellHelpButton .draw(win, white)
    pygame.display .update()
def keep_waiting():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( 'You continue to sit and wait.  Will anything happen?',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    draw_text( 'You can keep waiting..or choose the other options.',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -50 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    Wait2Button .draw( win, white)
    SearchButton .draw(win, white)
    YellHelpButton .draw(win, white)
    pygame .display .update()
def yell_choice_2():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( "Despite the warning, you yell 'Hello? Who's there?'",  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    pygame .display .update()
def yell_choice():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( "You yell 'Hello?', out into the darkness.",  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    draw_text( "Immediately you hear someone whisper back 'Be quiet!'.",  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -50 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    Yell2Button .draw( win, white)
    pygame .display .update()
def sit_choice():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( 'So you decided to sit and wait... nothing happens.  What now?',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    WaitButton .draw( win,  white )
    SearchButton .draw( win, white)
    YellHelpButton .draw( win, white)
    pygame .display .update()
def search_choice():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( 'So you decided to search.',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    pygame .display .update()
def beginning_question():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( 'The story of this game depends on your choices.  Do you wish to play?',  20,  halfwidth,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    PlayButton .draw( win,  white )
    pygame .display .update()
def begin_game():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    draw_text( "You wake up,  or...  at least you think you do.  Even though your eyes are open,",  fontsize,  halfwidth,  halfheight -300 )
    draw_text( "they still can't detect anything in the complete darkness that surrounds you.",  fontsize,  halfwidth,  halfheight -270 )
    draw_text( "What do you do?",  fontsize,  halfwidth,  halfheight -210 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    SitWaitButton .draw( win,  white )
    SearchButton .draw( win,  white )
    YellHelpButton .draw( win,  white )
    pygame .display .update()
##  game loop  ..  color,  x,  y,  msg
PlayButton = button( black,  halfwidth -50,  halfheight,  "Let's play." )
SitWaitButton = button( black,  halfwidth +200,  halfheight +50,  'Sit and wait...' )
SearchButton = button( black,  halfwidth -50,  halfheight +100,  'Get up and try to search your surroundings' )
YellHelpButton = button( black,  halfwidth +100,  halfheight +150,  'Yell to see if anyone is there' )
WaitButton = button( black,  halfwidth +100,  halfheight +200,  'Keep waiting...' )
Wait2Button = button( black, halfwidth +100, halfheight +250, 'Wait a little more...' )
Wait3Button = button( black, halfwidth +100, halfheight +200, 'Wait a bit more...' )
Yell2Button = button( black,  halfwidth -50,  halfheight +150,  'Yell again' )
game_begun = 'Input'  ##  beginning choice
search_option = 'Input'
sit_option = 'Input'
yell_option = 'Input'
wait_option = 'Input'
wait2_option = 'Input'
wait3_option = 'Input'
yell2_option = 'Input'
menu = True
lock_1 = True
sit_lock = True
wait_lock = True
wait_lock2 = True
wait_lock3 = True
yell_lock = True
while True:
    if yell2_option == 'Go':  yell_choice_2()
    elif yell_option == 'Go':   yell_choice()
    elif search_option == 'Go':   search_choice()
    elif wait3_option == 'Go':  keep_waiting_3()
    elif wait2_option == 'Go':  keep_waiting_2()
    elif wait_option == 'Go':   keep_waiting()
    elif sit_option == 'Go':    sit_choice()
    elif game_begun == 'Go':    begin_game()
    else:             beginning_question()
    for event in pygame .event .get():
        pos = pygame .mouse .get_pos()
        if event .type == pygame .QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame .quit()
            quit()
        ##  yes & no buttons for beginning question
        if event .type == pygame .MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  ##  menu if/else
            if PlayButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == True:
                menu = False
                game_begun = 'Go'
            elif YellHelpButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == False and lock_1 == True:
                wait_lock2 = True
                wait_lock3 = True
                lock_1 = False
                yell_lock = False
                yell_option = 'Go'
                print( "YellHelp button is working" )
            elif SitWaitButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == False and sit_lock == True:
                wait_lock = False
                sit_lock = False
                sit_option = 'Go'
                print( "SitWait button is working" )
            elif SearchButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == False and lock_1 == True:
                wait_lock2 = True
                wait_lock3 = True
                lock_1 = False
                search_option = 'Go'
                print( "Search button is working" )
            elif WaitButton .isOver( pos ) and wait_lock == False:
                lock_1 = True
                wait_lock = True
                wait_lock2 = False
                wait_option = 'Go'
                print( "Wait button is working" )
            elif Wait2Button .isOver( pos ) and wait_lock2 == False:
                lock_1 = True
                wait_lock2 = True
                wait_lock3 = False
                wait2_option = 'Go'
                print ("Wait button 2 is working")
            elif Wait3Button .isOver( pos ) and wait_lock3 == False:
                wait_lock2 = True
                wait_lock3 = True
                lock_1 = False
                wait3_option = 'Go'
                print("Wait button 3 is working")
            elif Yell2Button .isOver( pos ) and yell_lock == False:
                yell_lock = True
                yell2_option = 'Go'
                print ('Yell 2 button is working')
        if event .type == pygame .MOUSEMOTION:  ##  first option buttons
            PlayButton .color = black
            YellHelpButton .color = black
            SitWaitButton .color = black
            SearchButton .color = black
            WaitButton .color = black
            Wait2Button .color = black
            Wait3Button .color = black
            Yell2Button .color = black
            if PlayButton .isOver( pos ) and menu == True:
                PlayButton .color = blue
            elif YellHelpButton .isOver( pos ):
                YellHelpButton .color = blue
            elif SitWaitButton .isOver( pos ):
                SitWaitButton .color = blue
            elif SearchButton .isOver( pos ):
                SearchButton .color = blue
            elif WaitButton .isOver( pos ):
                WaitButton .color = blue
            elif Wait2Button .isOver( pos ):
                Wait2Button .color = blue
            elif Wait3Button .isOver( pos ):
                Wait3Button .color = blue
            elif Yell2Button .isOver( pos ):
                Yell2Button .color = blue
```

And now here is my button class code:::

```
import pygame
pygame .font .init()
screensize = Width, Height = 800, 700
halfwidth, halfheight = Width /2, Height /2
win = pygame .display .set_mode( screensize )
our_game_display = pygame .Surface( screensize )
font_name = pygame .font .get_default_font()
sansfont = pygame .font .SysFont( 'comicsans',  30 )
fontsize = 20
origin = 0, 0  ##  use variables for commonly used values
black = 0, 0, 0
blue = 0,  0,  139
white = 255, 255, 255
class button():
    def __init__( self,  color,  x,  y,  text ):
        self .color = color
        self .x = x
        self .y = y
        self .width = 20
        self .height = 10
        self .text = text
    def draw( self,  win,  outline = None ):
        ##  Call this method to draw button on screen
        if self .text != '':
            text = sansfont .render( self .text,  1,  white )
            self .width = text .get_width()
            self .height = text .get_height()
        if outline:
            pygame .draw .rect( win,  outline,  ( self .x -12,  self .y -12,  self .width +24,  self .height +24 ),  0 )
        pygame .draw .rect( win,  self .color,  ( self .x -10,  self .y -10,  self .width +20,  self .height +20 ),  0 )
        if self .text != '':
            win .blit( text,  ( self .x, self .y ) )
    def isOver( self,  pos ):
        ##  mouse position or a tuple of ( x,  y ) coordinates
        return pos[0] > self .x -13 and pos[0] < self .x -13 +self .width +26 \
        and pos[1] > self .y -13 and pos[1] < self .y -13 +self .height +26
```

Comment: If you have overlapping buttons, your isover checking should not be elifs , they should be regular ifs, otherwise the first one satisfied prevents the rest from being evaluated.

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you. That makes sense. I feel so dumb haha. I changed the elif conditions for button highlighting to Ifs and now Wait3Button is working. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought gamestate parameters were the hangup;  so I put those in a dictionary, to print them all out during clicks.  It'll be good for debugging.  Turned out to be `if` / `elif` chain, but I don't need credit for that.

Would like to mention that ya don't need to initialize objects more than once in your various modules though; can run into *circular imports* with overlapping values.  Might think something's one way and it ends up being another.

**Game1.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from pygame_init import *
from Game2 import *

##  Module for game logic

def keep_waiting_3():
    our_game_display .fill(black)
    text('Nothing still...wait! You hear something!',  0,  halfheight -100)
    win .blit(our_game_display,  origin)
    pygame .display .update()

def keep_waiting_2():
    our_game_display.fill(black)
    text('Are you sure you want to keep waiting?',  0,  halfheight -100)
    text("Maybe this isn't worth it...You could always choose the other options.",  0,  halfheight -50)
    win .blit(our_game_display,  origin)
    Wait3Button .draw( win,  white)
    SearchButton .draw(win,  white)
    YellHelpButton .draw(win,  white)
    pygame.display .update()

def keep_waiting():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    text( 'You continue to sit and wait.  Will anything happen?',  0,  halfheight -100 )
    text( 'You can keep waiting..or choose the other options.',  0,  halfheight -50 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    Wait2Button .draw( win,  white)
    SearchButton .draw(win,  white)
    YellHelpButton .draw(win,  white)
    pygame .display .update()

def yell_choice_2():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    text( "Despite the warning, you yell 'Hello? Who's there?'",  0,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    pygame .display .update()

def yell_choice():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    text( "You yell 'Hello?', out into the darkness.",  0,  halfheight -100 )
    text( "Immediately you hear someone whisper back 'Be quiet!'.",  0,  halfheight -50 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    Yell2Button .draw( win,  white)
    pygame .display .update()

def sit_choice():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    text( 'So you decided to sit and wait... nothing happens.  What now?',  0,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    WaitButton .draw( win,  white )
    SearchButton .draw( win,  white)
    YellHelpButton .draw( win,  white)
    pygame .display .update()

def search_choice():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    text( 'So you decided to search.',  0,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    pygame .display .update()

def beginning_question():
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    text( 'The story of this game depends on your choices.  Do you wish to play?',  0,  halfheight -100 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    PlayButton .draw( win,  white )
    pygame .display .update()

def begin_game():  ##  call to start again
    our_game_display .fill( black )
    text( 'You wake up, or...  at least you think you do.  Even though your eyes are open,',  0,  halfheight -300 )
    text( "they still can't detect anything in the complete darkness that surrounds you.",  0,  halfheight -270 )
    text( 'What do you do?',  0,  halfheight -210 )
    win .blit( our_game_display,  origin )
    SitWaitButton .draw( win,  white )
    SearchButton .draw( win,  white )
    YellHelpButton .draw( win,  white )
    pygame .display .update()

##  game loop  ..  color,  (x),  y,  msg
PlayButton = button( black,  0,  halfheight,  "Let's play." )
SitWaitButton = button( black,  1,  halfheight +50,  'Sit and wait...' )
SearchButton = button( black,  1,  halfheight +100,  'Get up and try to search your surroundings' )
YellHelpButton = button( black,  1,  halfheight +150,  'Yell to see if anyone is there' )
WaitButton = button( black,  1,  halfheight +200,  'Keep waiting...' )
Wait2Button = button( black,  1,  halfheight +250,  'Wait a little more...' )
Wait3Button = button( black,  1,  halfheight +200,  'Wait a bit more...' )
Yell2Button = button( black,  1,  halfheight +150,  'Yell again' )

while True:
    if yell2_option == 'Go':  yell_choice_2()
    elif yell_option == 'Go':   yell_choice()
    elif search_option == 'Go':   search_choice()
    elif wait3_option == 'Go':  keep_waiting_3()
    elif wait2_option == 'Go':  keep_waiting_2()
    elif wait_option == 'Go':   keep_waiting()
    elif sit_option == 'Go':    sit_choice()
    elif game_begun == 'Go':    begin_game()
    else:             beginning_question()

    for event in pygame .event .get():
        pos = pygame .mouse .get_pos()
        if event .type == pygame .QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame .quit()
            quit()

        ##  yes & no buttons for beginning question
        if event .type == pygame .MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  ##  menu if/else
            if PlayButton .isOver( pos ) and para['menu'] == True:
                para['menu'] = False
                game_begun = 'Go'

            elif YellHelpButton .isOver( pos ) and para['menu'] == False and para['lock_1'] == True:
                para['wait_lock2'] = True
                para['wait_lock3'] = True
                para['lock_1'] = False
                para['yell_lock'] = False
                yell_option = 'Go'
                print( 'YellHelp button is working', para )

            elif SitWaitButton .isOver( pos ) and para['menu'] == False and para['sit_lock'] == True:
                para['wait_lock'] = False
                para['sit_lock'] = False
                sit_option = 'Go'
                print( 'SitWait button is working', para )

            elif SearchButton .isOver( pos ) and para['menu'] == False and para['lock_1'] == True:
                para['wait_lock2'] = True
                para['wait_lock3'] = True
                para['lock_1'] = False
                search_option = 'Go'
                print( 'Search button is working', para )

            elif WaitButton .isOver( pos ) and para['wait_lock'] == False:
                para['lock_1'] = True
                para['wait_lock'] = True
                para['wait_lock2'] = False
                wait_option = 'Go'
                print( 'Wait button is working', para )

            elif Wait2Button .isOver( pos ) and para['wait_lock2'] == False:
                para['lock_1'] = True
                para['wait_lock2'] = True
                para['wait_lock3'] = False
                wait2_option = 'Go'
                print( 'Wait button 2 is working', para )

            elif Wait3Button .isOver( pos ) and para['wait_lock3'] == False:
                para['wait_lock2'] = True
                para['wait_lock3'] = True
                para['lock_1'] = False
                wait3_option = 'Go'
                print( 'Wait button 3 is working', para )

            elif Yell2Button .isOver( pos ) and para['yell_lock'] == False:
                para['yell_lock'] = True
                yell2_option = 'Go'
                print( 'Yell 2 button is working', para )

        if event .type == pygame .MOUSEMOTION:  ##  first option buttons
            PlayButton .color = black
            YellHelpButton .color = black
            SitWaitButton .color = black
            SearchButton .color = black
            WaitButton .color = black
            Wait2Button .color = black
            Wait3Button .color = black
            Yell2Button .color = black

            if PlayButton .isOver( pos ) and para['menu'] == True:
                PlayButton .color = blue
            if YellHelpButton .isOver( pos ):  YellHelpButton .color = blue
            if SitWaitButton .isOver( pos ):  SitWaitButton .color = blue
            if SearchButton .isOver( pos ):  SearchButton .color = blue
            if WaitButton .isOver( pos ):  WaitButton .color = blue
            if Wait2Button .isOver( pos ):  Wait2Button .color = blue
            if Wait3Button .isOver( pos ):  Wait3Button .color = blue
            if Yell2Button .isOver( pos ):  Yell2Button .color = blue
```

---

**Game2.py**

```
from pygame_init import *

##  module for helper functions

class button():
    def __init__( self,  color,  x,  y,  text ):
        self .color = color
        self .x = x
        self .y = y
        self .width = 20
        self .height = 10
        self .text = text

    def draw( self,  win,  outline = None ):
        ##  Call this method to draw button on screen
        if self .text != '':
            text = buttonfont .render( self .text,  1,  white )
            self .width = text .get_width()
            self .height = text .get_height()
            ##  optional x parameter.  If x pos given, use it, otherwise generate
            if self .x == -1:  ##  -1 = left align
                self .x = 20
            elif self .x == 0:  ##  0 = center align
                self .x = halfwidth -( self .width /2 )
            elif self .x == 1:  ##  1 = right align
                self .x = Width -self .width -20
        if outline:
            pygame .draw .rect( win,  outline,  ( self .x -12,  self .y -12,  self .width +24,  self .height +24 ),  0 )
        pygame .draw .rect( win,  self .color,  ( self .x -10,  self .y -10,  self .width +20,  self .height +20 ),  0 )
        if self .text != '':
            win .blit( text,  ( self .x, self .y ) )

    def isOver( self,  pos ):
        ##  mouse position or a tuple of ( x,  y ) coordinates
        return pos[0] > self .x -13 and pos[0] < self .x -13 +self .width +26 \
        and pos[1] > self .y -13 and pos[1] < self .y -13 +self .height +26


def text( text,  xx,  yy ):  ##  Function to position and draw text on screen
    antialias = True
    text_surface = textfont .render( text,  antialias,  white )
    text_rect = text_surface .get_rect()
    if abs( xx ) <= 1:  ##  generate x pos if  -1, 0, 1
        ww = text_surface .get_width() /2

        ##  optional x parameter.  If given, use it, otherwise justify
        if xx == -1:  ##  -1 = left align
            xx = ww +20
        elif xx == 0:  ##  0 = center align
            xx = halfwidth
        elif xx == 1:  ##  1 = right align
            xx = Width -ww -20

    text_rect .center = ( xx,  yy )
    our_game_display .blit( text_surface,  text_rect )
```

---

**pygame_init.py**

```
import pygame

##  Module to hold all of the initial states of variables.
##  Essentially globals, to be shared among the other modules.

pygame .init()
pygame .font .init()  ##  don't need to initialize font every turn, just do it once

screensize = Width, Height = 800, 700
halfwidth, halfheight = Width /2, Height /2

win = pygame .display .set_mode( screensize )
our_game_display = pygame .Surface( screensize )

origin = 0, 0  ##  use variables for commonly used values
black = 0, 0, 0
blue = 0,  0,  139
white = 255, 255, 255

textfont = pygame .font .SysFont( 'comicsans',  28 )
buttonfont = pygame .font .SysFont( 'comicsans',  30 )

game_begun = 'Input'  ##  beginning choice
search_option = 'Input'
sit_option = 'Input'
yell_option = 'Input'
wait_option = 'Input'
wait2_option = 'Input'
wait3_option = 'Input'
yell2_option = 'Input'

para = {  ##  gamestate parameters
    'menu': True,
    'lock_1': True,
    'sit_lock': True,
    'wait_lock': True,
    'wait_lock2': True,
    'wait_lock3': True,
    'yell_lock': True,
}
```

Comment: Wow. The code makes much more sense and is even easier to use now. Thanks for revising it once more, I really appreciate it! You've given me a really great base for my game.